# Laravel 9: Custom login

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-9

I am trying to change the default table that laravel 9 uses to authenticate the users.
But while I can see that user is authenticanted in the login function of `LoginController` when I try to redirect to home page as logged in user I get the error

> Route [login] not defined.

If the user is logged in why does it try to redirect to `login` route and not to `home`

Here is my `LoginController.php`

```
public function login(LoginRequest $request)
    { 
        $credentials = $request->getCredentials();
/*
        if(!Auth::validate($credentials)):
            return redirect()->to('login')
                ->withErrors(trans('auth.failed'));
        endif;
*/
        $user = Auth::getProvider()->retrieveByCredentials($credentials);

        if(empty($user)){
            return redirect()->to('login')
                ->withErrors(trans('auth.failed'));
        }

        Auth::login($user);

        //Auth::check() returns true here!

        return $this->authenticated($request, $user);
    }

    /**
     * Handle response after user authenticated
     * 
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Auth $user
     * 
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user) 
    {
        return redirect()->intended('/home');
    }
```

and here are my routes in `web.php`

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function()
{   
    
    

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['guest']], function() {
        /**
         * Register Routes
         */
        Route::get('/register', 'RegisterController@show')->name('register.show');
        Route::post('/register', 'RegisterController@register')->name('register.perform');

        /**
         * Login Routes
         */
        Route::get('/login',  'LoginController@show')->name('login.show');
        Route::post('/login', 'LoginController@login')->name('login.perform');
       
        


    });

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {

        Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home.index');
       

        /**
         * Logout Routes
         */
        Route::get('/logout', 'LogoutController@perform')->name('logout.perform');
    });
});
```

Comment: `redirect()->to('login')`, but you don't have a route named `login`, but you do have one named `->name('login.show')`. Voting to close question as a typo; you used the wrong name, and your code is telling you exactly this.

Comment: @TimLewis but why should redirect to login? I am redirecting to home and the user is already logged-in authenticated

Comment: You have this in your code: `return redirect()->to('login')`; Is that the line that's doing this erroneous redirect? Or is that happening somewhere else? You might just need to look for other instances of `route('login')` (for example), and replace that with `route('login.show')`, or change your name to `->name('login')`, since that is the expected default for Laravel authentication.

Comment: @TimLewis if I change  `->name('login.show')` to `->name('login')` then I get this error: `Route [auth.login] not defined.

`

Comment: Are your `auth` and `guest` Middlewares custom too? Or are they still using Laravel's default? I think you're running into issues with using your custom login logic with Laravel's built-in authentication logic (i.e. redirecting to named routes that you now do not have defined). Review the documentation on Authentication: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication and see if anything in there helps. But your error is clear; somewhere in your code, it's trying to access a named route that you do not have; you need to fix that 

Comment: Laravel 8,9 dont understand ```'ControllerName@action'```, for example ```[ContrName::class, 'actionName']```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Auth::attempt() to authenticate.
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#authenticating-users

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post link-only answers but summarize the linked content or its relevant parts a little. A link may become invalid or outdated and in that case, your answer would be useless in the future.